# Can I do an UpsertRequest that checks if the name of the entity exists?

Tags: c#, microsoft-dynamics, upsert

In C#, I'm writing a program that transfers data from an old Microsoft Dynamics CRM system to a new one.

For most of the entities, I can use the UpsertRequest. Though, for contacts and accounts, there are already records in the new environment. As I don't want to have doubles, I would like to have the UpsertRequest check on the "Name" field in case of accounts and on "Fullname" in case of contacts.

Would that be possible? I (searched a lot and) cannot find examples on this. If not, what would be the best way to proceed?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

for such case I would make a plugin on message create of contact and account such like this one :

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        ITracingService tracingService =
           (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
            serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory =
            (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        IOrganizationService organizationService = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

        Entity TargetEntity = new Entity();


        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            TargetEntity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];


            QueryExpression queryDuplicateDetect = new QueryExpression(TargetEntity.LogicalName);

            if (TargetEntity.LogicalName == "account" && TargetEntity.Attributes.Contains("name"))
            {
                queryDuplicateDetect.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "name" });
                queryDuplicateDetect.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, TargetEntity["name"].ToString()));
            }
            else if (TargetEntity.LogicalName == "contact" && TargetEntity.Attributes.Contains("fullname"))
            {
                queryDuplicateDetect.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "fullname" });
                queryDuplicateDetect.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("fullname", ConditionOperator.Equal, TargetEntity["fullname"].ToString()));
            }

            try
            {
                EntityCollection resultsColl = organizationService.RetrieveMultiple(queryDuplicateDetect);
                if (resultsColl.Entities.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Entity e in resultsColl.Entities)
                    {
                        tracingService.Trace("Record Found with ID {0}", e.Id);
                    }

                    //log results in some entity for more info 
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Duplicate detected.");

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

and on the create side i'll use simple try catch to skip existing records

```
 Entity x = new Entity("account");
            x["name"] = "mohamed0";

            Entity y = new Entity("contact");
            y["fullname"] = "mohamed";

            Entity z = new Entity("contact");
            z["fullname"] = "mohamed";


            try
            {


                var r = _orgService.Create(x);
                r = _orgService.Create(y);
                r = _orgService.Create(z);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw;
            }
```

hope this will help.